# Date column autosorted by twig

Tags: symfony, sorting, datetime, twig

I have a problem with one of my page in my website.
I'm using Symfony 2.
I'm passing a multidimensionnal array with a `dateCreated` field (datetime), sorted in ascending order. In Twig, my column is sorted only when I format it into date(`m/d/Y`), but I want to display it in `d/m/Y` format.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on how to ask and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your specific issue and provide you with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Twig does not have a built-in filter table. I assume you are using some custom table JavaScript, right?